# I need help using a variable to populate a table to create a Javascript scatter plot

Tags: javascript, function, variables, var

I am trying to use this Javascript to create a scatter plot: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter/gray

Im using it just like it shows there and when i copy the graph with the info from the example it works fine.

I created a function to populate the table to how I want...this is how my code looks

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">

<script>
    var rateValueData = <?php echo json_encode($data);?>;


$(function (scatter) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Height Versus Weight of 507 Individuals by Gender'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Heinz  2003'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Height (cm)'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Weight (kg)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 70,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 5,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                        }
                    }
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Female',
            color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
            data: THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO USE THE VARIABLE!!!!

        }, ]
    });
});

</script>
```

so the function to create the Variable works but then how can i use that variable to populate the data for the graph

This is what the variable displays at when I echo it out:

```
var rateValueData = [["7.59090","104.2"],["1.58181","101.3636364"],["0.86363","106.5090909"],["0.7","73.86363636"],["2.7","94.38571429"],["2.48333","104.4727273"],["22.45","103"],["4.09090","105.3888889"],["1.91818","102.2909091"],["1.85","94.82727273"],["62.1","102.7666667"],["6.31818","100.7454545"],["2.31818","107.9545455"],["5.8","99.9625"],["1.92727","105.4727273"],["1.1","102.3"],["16.95","99.40909091"],["0.6","96.35"],["81.68","103.7909091"],["11.5818","116.7363636"],["2.64545","104.8111111"],["1.72","105.73"],["1.24545","104.9272727"],["1.35454","101.9363636"],["32.6363","99.05"],["15.5727","102.05"],["0.8","103.6"],["2.37272","109.7818182"],["0.9","99.62727273"],["4.05454","93.06363636"],["1.1","101.2272727"],["2.70909","102.5888889"],["1.35454","106.3363636"],["41.2181","101.3375"],["0.52727","104.4363636"],["14.8818","107.3909091"],["2.18333","98.82727273"],["3.7","66.70909091"],["10.3272","113.5545455"],["2.31428","96.51818182"],["1.14","101.7727273"],["11.9727","102.4272727"],["1.68571","101.3727273"],["1.48181","102.1454545"],["1.3","103.5181818"],["12.3090","100.8545455"],["0.91818","101.9272727"],["6.51","92.75"],["10.7818","98.05"],["21.46","97.95"],["8.35","98.85"],["7.6625","98.53"],["2.79090","106.1909091"],["1.17","107.3090909"],["19.9181","107.6909091"],["0.61666","50.03636364"],["2.68181","104.5818182"],["1.11428","80"],["1.93333","105.0454545"],["0.84545","99.36"],["2.46363","105.8714286"],["1.49090","104.9272727"],["50.4545","106.6636364"],["1.24545","103.9363636"],["1.01818","102.1636364"],["1.12727","104.7090909"],["2.22222","96.01818182"],["7.83636","101.4090909"],["4.5","98.98181818"],["8.99090","116.1571429"],["1.67272","105.1545455"],["6.25","106.5727273"]];
```

That is the data that I need to plot in the scatter chart.

Can anybody help me out?

Let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your array contains string instead of numeric value.

Try with

```
var rateValueData = [[7.59090,104.2],[1.58181,101.3636364],[0.86363,106.5090909],[0.7,73.86363636],[2.7,94.38571429],[2.48333,104.4727273],[22.45,103],[4.09090,105.3888889],[1.91818,102.2909091],[1.85,94.82727273],[62.1,102.7666667],[6.31818,100.7454545],[2.31818,107.9545455],[5.8,99.9625],[1.92727,105.4727273],[1.1,102.3],[16.95,99.40909091],[0.6,96.35],[81.68,103.7909091],[11.5818,116.7363636],[2.64545,104.8111111],[1.72,105.73],[1.24545,104.9272727],[1.35454,101.9363636],[32.6363,99.05],[15.5727,102.05],[0.8,103.6],[2.37272,109.7818182],[0.9,99.62727273],[4.05454,93.06363636],[1.1,101.2272727],[2.70909,102.5888889],[1.35454,106.3363636],[41.2181,101.3375],[0.52727,104.4363636],[14.8818,107.3909091],[2.18333,98.82727273],[3.7,66.70909091],[10.3272,113.5545455],[2.31428,96.51818182],[1.14,101.7727273],[11.9727,102.4272727],[1.68571,101.3727273],[1.48181,102.1454545],[1.3,103.5181818],[12.3090,100.8545455],[0.91818,101.9272727],[6.51,92.75],[10.7818,98.05],[21.46,97.95],[8.35,98.85],[7.6625,98.53],[2.79090,106.1909091],[1.17,107.3090909],[19.9181,107.6909091],[0.61666,50.03636364],[2.68181,104.5818182],[1.11428,80],[1.93333,105.0454545],[0.84545,99.36],[2.46363,105.8714286],[1.49090,104.9272727],[50.4545,106.6636364],[1.24545,103.9363636],[1.01818,102.1636364],[1.12727,104.7090909],[2.22222,96.01818182],[7.83636,101.4090909],[4.5,98.98181818],[8.99090,116.1571429],[1.67272,105.1545455],[6.25,106.5727273]];
```

[This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WVp9d/1/) is throwing an error

While [this is](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WVp9d/2/) working

Comment: That worked! Interesting...so why does it now work with rateValueData = <?php echo json_encode($data);?>; ?

Comment: if you look carefully, your values are enclosed with in `""`

Comment: I did notice that. Does that just happen automatically or was it something in my code?
thanks a lot man!

Comment: @clo3o5 I'm not a php guy so I don't know much about the serverside script which generated the value. Only thing to be kept in mind is the array should contain numeric values not string